# Estilos no bootstrap não estão funcionando

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

**Primeira vez usando o bootstrap (programando em HTML e CSS tambem) então desculpa se a pergunta for muito obvia, estou tentando aplicar um codigo do bootstrat porem o css não esta sendo aplicado.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <section style="background-color: #eee;">
        <div class="container py-5">
    
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
    
            <div class="card" id="chat2">
                <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-3">
                <h5 class="mb-0">Chat</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Let's Chat
                    App</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" data-mdb-perfect-scrollbar="true" style="position: relative; height: 400px">
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava3-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 ms-3 mb-1 rounded-3" style="background-color: #f5f6f7;">Hi</p>
                    <p class="small p-2 ms-3 mb-1 rounded-3" style="background-color: #f5f6f7;">How are you ...???
                    </p>
                    <p class="small p-2 ms-3 mb-1 rounded-3" style="background-color: #f5f6f7;">What are you doing
                        tomorrow? Can we come up a bar?</p>
                    <p class="small ms-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted">23:58</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="divider d-flex align-items-center mb-4">
                    <p class="text-center mx-3 mb-0" style="color: #a2aab7;">Today</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end mb-4 pt-1">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">Hiii, I'm good.</p>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">How are you doing?</p>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">Long time no see! Tomorrow
                        office. will
                        be free on sunday.</p>
                    <p class="small me-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted d-flex justify-content-end">00:06</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava4-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start mb-4">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava3-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 ms-3 mb-1 rounded-3" style="background-color: #f5f6f7;">Okay</p>
                    <p class="small p-2 ms-3 mb-1 rounded-3" style="background-color: #f5f6f7;">We will go on
                        Sunday?</p>
                    <p class="small ms-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted">00:07</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end mb-4">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">That's awesome!</p>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">I will meet you Sandon Square
                        sharp at
                        10 AM</p>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">Is that okay?</p>
                    <p class="small me-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted d-flex justify-content-end">00:09</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava4-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start mb-4">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava3-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 ms-3 mb-1 rounded-3" style="background-color: #f5f6f7;">Okay i will meet
                        you on
                        Sandon Square</p>
                    <p class="small ms-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted">00:11</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end mb-4">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">Do you have pictures of Matley
                        Marriage?</p>
                    <p class="small me-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted d-flex justify-content-end">00:11</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava4-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start mb-4">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava3-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 ms-3 mb-1 rounded-3" style="background-color: #f5f6f7;">Sorry I don't
                        have. i
                        changed my phone.</p>
                    <p class="small ms-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted">00:13</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end">
                    <div>
                    <p class="small p-2 me-3 mb-1 text-white rounded-3 bg-primary">Okay then see you on sunday!!
                    </p>
                    <p class="small me-3 mb-3 rounded-3 text-muted d-flex justify-content-end">00:15</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava4-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 1" style="width: 45px; height: 100%;">
                </div>
    
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center p-3">
                <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-chat/ava3-bg.webp"
                    alt="avatar 3" style="width: 40px; height: 100%;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                    placeholder="Type message">
                <a class="ms-1 text-muted" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i></a>
                <a class="ms-3 text-muted" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></a>
                <a class="ms-3" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
        </div>
    </section>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eaí, beleza ?
Está faltando linkar o bootstrap ao seu projeto, no seu "head" juntamente onde você linkou o style.css, precisa linkar o bootstrap. Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Na documentação do Bootstrap é explicado melhor, confira diretamente no site dele: https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).